# Replacing interfaces by abstract classes in Bridge pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, bridge

Looking at [this explanation](http://www.oodesign.com/bridge-pattern.html) of the Bridge pattern, it says that the Abstraction and Implementors are interfaces. However I don't see the reason why they can't be Abstract classes instead.

**Example:** Imagine that all the constructors from AbstractionImp will always receive 1 parameter, the Implementor, and the only thing the constructor does, is to store that parameter in a AbstractionImp field. Like this:

```
public AbstractionImp(Implementor implementor) {
   this.implementor  = implementor;
}
```

So why instead of repeating this alll over the other AbstractImp classes, why not just have this instead? Note: in this case AbstractionImp extends Abstraction which is an abstract class.

```
public AbstractionImp(Implementor implementor) {
   super(implementor);
}

public Abstraction(Implementor implementor) {
   this.implementor = implementor;
}
```

Am I violating the Bridge Pattern if I replace the interfaces by abstract classes? Doing it like this, a lot of boilerplate code can be avoided.

Comment: An abstract class defines an interface. It is, as its name states, an abstraction.  So, it can be used in a Bridge Pattern without "violating" the pattern.

Comment: Using an abstract class makes your API more restrictive. Now `Abstraction` **must** be the base for all classes like `AbstractionImp`. Meaning you lose some flexibility

Comment: @flkes, good point.  Personally would go with the interface, and have the abstract class implement it.  Gives the benefit of code re-use with the flexibility of the not being tied to the abstract class.

Comment: Really useful comments! Cheers! If you want, put it as an answer and I'll mark it.